# missing required icon file

Tags: ios, mobile

Error: Asset validation failed Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPad of exactly '152x152' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 10.0

I am trying to open up Images.xcassets and then open appicon to fill in the missing icons.

but when i try to open the project navigator, the following is shown

[image]

I have tried the all the other suggestions, but the wrong project navigator and Images.xcassets not showing up is confusing me.

Comment: That `Images` is xcassets file. You can right click on it and then show it in finder to check. Xcode hides the file type extension.